# Bonding on centos only and switch without LAG enabled vs Bonding on centos and swtich with LAG enabled

Tags: switch, bonding, netgear, lag

I am a little confused on Bonding on Centos side and Link aggregation on netgear switch side. Would mean a lot if someone can clear it out.

Using switch Netgear XS708E which does not support IEEE 802.3 ad Dynamic Link Aggregation (http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/GS105E/ProSAFE_Plus_Utility_UM_EN.pdf?_ga=2.188669345.807201846.1548399462-1647759038.1548399462) (Page: 14)

Environment 1:
- Configured bonding(port 2 and 3) on centos in any mode other than 802.3ad (mode=4) and LAG group is not enabled on switch

Environment 2:
- Configured bonding(port 2 and 3) on centos in any mode other than 802.3ad (mode=4) and LAG group(port 2 and 3) is enabled on switch

What is the difference in the above two configurations? If Netgear XS708E does not support XS708E what is the use of the LAG group settings as specified in the manual?

A separate doubt: As specified in the above manual XS708E does not support 802.3 ad mode. But in this link (http://www.decryptedtech.com/netgear-prosafe-xs708e-8-port-10gbe-switch-review?limit=1&showall=1), it is written "You also can setup Link Aggregation Groups for trunking or for 802.3ad groups". Is this a typo?